# “Uninitialized constant” error when trying to create Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jira, dashing

I am working on dashing dashboard and trying to add a Jira widget.In the widget code it is trying to create and initialize a Client object. As shown in code below

```
require  'Jira'

SCHEDULER.every '5m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  client = Jira::Client.new({
    :username => ENV['Talal'],
    :password => ENV['Talal123'],
    :site => "http://192.168.99.100:32768",
    :auth_type => :basic,
    :context_path => "/jira"
  })
```

But as I gets to this line `client = Jira::Client.new`. An exception occurs which states that `uninitialized constant Jira::Client`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the gem you should be using is `jira-ruby`. Once you install it, Bundler should automatically require it for you, meaning if you're in a Rails environment, you shouldn't need to do `require 'Jira'`.

If you don't want it required application-wide, BTW, you should add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jira-ruby', require: false

# then in your scheduler, you have to explicitly require it as before:
require 'jira-ruby'

SCHEDULER.every '5m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  client = Jira::Client.new({
    :username => ENV['Talal'],
    :password => ENV['Talal123'],
    :site => "http://192.168.99.100:32768",
    :auth_type => :basic,
    :context_path => "/jira"
  })
```

Additional [information here](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby)